# How to properly fix [sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set]

Tags: linux, fedora, sudo

I've run this:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/bin/
```

and after that got this every time when I use sudo:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

I use Fedora 37. Does anybody know the way to fix this properly?

Answer (score 2):

First, find another way to become root. Either `machinectl shell` or `systemd-run --shell` should still work, as they don't rely on setuid binaries (not in /usr/bin, at least).

If nothing works, reboot into rescue mode (add `rescue` to the kernel command line at the boot menu); sudo won't be necessary there as everything starts as root to begin with.

As a preliminary fix, use `chmod u+s` (or `chmod 4755`) to manually mark /usr/bin/sudo as "setuid" (and do the same on /usr/bin/su just in case).

For a complete fix, it's best to use your package manager (rpm+dnf) to find and reinstall all affected packages, as there are quite a few other programs in /usr/bin that lost their "setuid" and/or "setgid" privilege bits.

1. Use `rpm -Va` to verify which other files no longer match what was originally installed from packages (probably `rpm -Va | grep /usr/bin` and maybe `| awk '$1 ~ /[MUGP]/'`).
2. Use `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/whatever` to find out which package each file belongs to.
3. Use `dnf reinstall whatever` to reinstall the packages.

Finally, take a look at the files and verify that they have the correct permissions – if you `ls -l`, you should see "rws" instead of "rwx" on /usr/bin/sudo; and if you use `stat` to check the same mode in octal you should see 04755 (or 02755) instead of just 0755.

Comment: I got root by this  'systemd-run --shell', thank you so much for this) 
I'm on step (3) now, and this is output 
https://notes.io/wwpu3

should I reinstall all of them?

Comment: Yes – some of them had the setuid flag (u+s), some of them were setgid (g+s), some were both, and it's easiest to let the package manager tidy it up. I don't really know how to use Fedora's package manager, but `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/whatever` will at least tell you which package each file belongs to; then you probably do [dnf reinstall](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/rlsd2u/how_to_cleanly_reinstall_package/hphuesr/).

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't be a root user by using the "su" command because I didn't have a
root password, but instead I used this command to become a root user: `systemd-run --shell`
and after that:
`chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo` My problem is
solved.